# Sendgrid brand link with nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, sendgrid

We try to set a brand link with custom ssl with this doc https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/custom-ssl-configurations/.

We follow it, and now we have a proxy, with certificat, and that's redirect to sendgrid.net.

Support tell us that their test say "FAIL: We did not get a 200 response back from the test 'https' click tracking link." And tell us also that certificat wildcard on proxy is not supported.

I don't understand the wildcard reason, and the proxy send not a 200, because sendgrid.net send a 404

So I don't understand what to do.

We use nginx and this example to implement our proxy : https://gist.github.com/jjhiew/cbbd26da313fc550467e303a6c6f8177

Comment: I'm having the same problem with SendGrid. I don't think their support people understand custom SSL configurations. Their support people seem to be contradicting their own documentation. I figure this out, I'll post it here.

Comment: @Winston any update?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reminder. We do have it working, but I forgot to post it here. The general idea is to
have branded click requests go to our own server, which has the TLS certifiate. I.e. link.mysite.com
goes to our own server instead of SendGrid. Our server accepts those requests, makes the identical
request to SendGrid. Whatever SendGrid replies to our server, we send back to the browser.

I'm not sure but I think the SendGrid support folks had to flip some switch. But that might be wrong. I do remember I talked to them, and I remember they didn't understand this proxy situation. Did I finally get someone who did, or did I get it working without them, I'm not sure.

Below is the code we use for this (Ruby on Rails):

```
# Allow SendGrid Click Tracking to use HTTPS
#
# SendGrid click tracking uses the host 'link.example.com' but HSTS requires that host
# respond to HTTPS. However SendGrid does not have our certificate. So instead point
# link.example.com to this proxy, and we make the same request to sendgrid.
#
# see: https://sendgrid.com/docs/ui/account-and-settings/custom-ssl-configurations/
#
# Configuring SendGrid, Heroku, and DNSimple for Click Tracking and unsubscribes
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   Sendgrid > Sender Authentication > Link Branding
#     Create branded link for example.com
#     Advanced Settings > Custom link subdomain: link
#
#   DNS > make the CNAME records they mention
#   Sendgrid >
#     verify branded links so they are activated.
#     Make link the default.
#
#   Heroku > configure subdomain for link.example.com
#   DNS > change CNAME record so link.example.com points to Heroku, e.g. blah.blah.herokudns.com
#
#   Test:
#       Unsubscribe links that start with link.example.com/___ should work now.
#
#   Sendgrid > Tracking > Click Tracking > ON
#
#   Test:
#     Send a test Frisky Friday.
#     Follow link to article--it should start with link.example.com
#     SendGrid increments the Click Tracking counter
class SendgridLinkProxyController < ActionController::Base
  SENDGRID_CLICK_TRACKING_URL = 'https://sendgrid.net'.freeze

  def index
    # Make matching request to SendGrid
    sendgrid_url = URI.parse("#{SENDGRID_CLICK_TRACKING_URL}#{request.env['ORIGINAL_FULLPATH']}").to_s
    sendgrid_headers = { 'Host' => CFG.SENDGRID_PROXY_HOSTNAME }

    Rails.logger.info("sendgrid_link_proxy_controller.rb: fetching #{sendgrid_url}, headers: #{sendgrid_headers}")
    sendgrid_response = HTTParty.get(sendgrid_url, headers: sendgrid_headers, follow_redirects: false) # , debug_output: STDOUT)

    # Make matching response to browser
    user_response_status = sendgrid_response.code
    response.set_header('location', sendgrid_response.headers['location'])
    Rails.logger.info("sendgrid_link_proxy_controller.rb: responding status_code: #{user_response_status}, location header: #{response.header['location']}")
    render html: sendgrid_response.body.html_safe, # We are trusting SendGrid. Winston think's that's OK. [Winston Dec 2018]
           status: user_response_status
  end
end
```

And here's an RSpec file to go with it:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe SendgridLinkProxyController do

  describe '#index' do
    before do
      @sendgrid_response = {
        headers: {},
        body: '<html>SENDGRID BODY</html>',
        code: 200
      }
      request.env['ORIGINAL_FULLPATH'] = '/wf/click?upn=BLAH'
      CFG.SENDGRID_PROXY_HOSTNAME = 'link.example.com'
    end

    subject do
      allow(HTTParty)
        .to receive(:get)
        .and_return(double('Mock Sendgrid Response', @sendgrid_response))
      get :index, params: {a: 'click'}
    end

    it 'requests page from sendgrid with same path and with Host header' do
      expect(HTTParty).to receive(:get)
        .with('https://sendgrid.net/wf/click?upn=BLAH',
              headers: { 'Host' => 'link.example.com' },
              follow_redirects: false
             )

      subject
    end

    context 'when receiving a click-tracking redirect link' do
      before do
        @sendgrid_response[:code] = 302
        @sendgrid_response[:headers]['location'] = 'https://example.com/TARGET'
      end

      it 'redirects browser to target link' do
        subject

        expect(response.status).to eq(302)
        expect(response.headers['location']).to eq('https://example.com/TARGET')
      end
    end

    context 'when receiving an unsubcribe link' do
      before do
        request.env['ORIGINAL_FULLPATH'] = '/wf/unsubscribe?upn=BLAH'
      end

      it 'renders sendgrid\'s unsubscribe page' do
        subject

        expect(response.body).to eq('<html>SENDGRID BODY</html>')
      end
    end
  end
end
```